Calendly API - Meeting Accepted?
I am using the Calendly API V2 and trying to determine if a meeting has been accepted by the user. The docs say if the status of the "invitee" is 'active' then they have accepted. However the status appears active regardless of whether or not they accepted. Anyone know of a workaround?
Also for those of you new to the API, ChatGPT helps a lot in solving many of these issues. Ask it something like: Write a script in php using Calendly API V2 that gets my organization uri and uses that to list the events I have upcoming.
Saved me A LOT of time. -Gabe
